# What does "spare" mean in the context below?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

Yes, thank you," she said. "Swinburne fails, when all is said, because he is, well, indelicate. There are many of his poems that should never be read. Every line of the really great poets is filled with beautiful truth, and calls to all that is high and noble in the human. Not a line of the great poets **can be spared** without impoverishing the world by that much."

Answer (score 1):

It means that not a line can be dispensed with, removed, cleared, forgotten in such a way as for this loss to go unnoticed.

Comment: if one were to answer this type of question here (And this probably shouldn’t be, as written, because of lack of research) one would provide a dictionary definition, citing sources, and an explantion of why that definition fits OP’s usage.